# Why are By.CSS and By.CLASS_NAME selectors not working efficiently when using Selenium and Python to scrape data from a website?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait, getelementsbyclassname

So I am trying to use selenium to find specific items on a webpage, but I want to make it universal for similar pages. My current code is below.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Applications/chromedriver_mac_arm64 (1)/chromedriver')
driver.get(
    "https://www.usgbc.org/projects/?Country=%5B%22United+States%22%5D&Rating+System=%5B%22New+Construction%22%5D&Rating+Version=%5B%22v2009%22%5D&Certification=%5B%22Platinum%22%5D&State=%5B%22Texas%22%5D")
# check this is the right website
# print(driver.title)

# list of building names to quickly check what has been added
buildings = []
locations = []

# lists for items on project page
sqft_amount = []

# dataframe to collect all building information
df_main = pd.DataFrame()
# dataframe to collect building profile data on page
df_profile_data = pd.DataFrame()
# dataframe to collect scorecard data
df_scorecard = pd.DataFrame()

# make this happen for next button

while True:
    
    try:
        
        project_profiles = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "grid-item--title")
    
        for i in range(len(project_profiles)):
            # Wait for page to load as order of elements will be incorrect otherwise
            time.sleep(1)
            
            project_profiles = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "grid-item--title")  # Find the list again
            # append and add to df
            building_name = project_profiles[i].text
            buildings.append(building_name)
            print(building_name)

            # enable if checking all
            # building profile page information grab##############################
            # load building profile page
            building_profile_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@id='result-grid']//h1[text()='{building_name}']")
            building_profile_link.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            
            # address
            address = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'projectAddress')
            for i in address:
                building_address = i.text
                locations.append(building_address)
            print(locations)
            
            # get values from tables on page
            row_data = []
            col_data = []
            
            # the row typicaly starts with td[]##
            # copy path of first row then make it end in /td, copy Xpath not entire path
            rows = WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='certificates']/tbody/tr/td")))
            # the col typicaly starts with th[]##
            # copy path of first row then make it end in /th, copy Xpath not entire path
            columns = WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='certificates']/thead/tr/th")))
            
            for row in rows:
                row_data.append(row.text)
                
            for cols in columns:
                col_data.append(cols.text)
            
            #time.sleep(5)
            
            print(row_data, "row")
            print(col_data, "col")
            
            df_profile_data.append(row_data)
            
            ################################SQFT##########################################
            
            #import requests
            get_url = driver.current_url
            print("The current url is:"+str(get_url))
            
            URL = get_url
            html = requests.get(URL).content
            df_list = pd.read_html(html)
            df = df_list[-1]
            SQFT = df.iloc[0,1]
            SQFT = SQFT.replace('sq ft', '')
            sqft_amount.append(SQFT)
            #print(SQFT)
            
            ######### load credit score card page##########################################
            #building_scorecard_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@id='project-details--wrapper']//h1[text()='Scorecard']")
            building_scorecard_link = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Scorecard')
            #/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]
            building_scorecard_link.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            
            # grab data on categories point totals
            point_data = []
            point_total = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'category-score')
            for points in point_total:
                point_data.append(points.text)
            print('cat scores', point_data)
            
            # category names
            cat_names = []
            #expand credit areas
            sus_link = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'category-title')
            #sus_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'category-title')))
            for i in sus_link:
                i.click()
                print('cat_names:', i.text)
                cat_names.append(i.text)
                #if i == 'SUSTAINABLE SITES':
                    
            # grab specfic credit name
            #rows = WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='certificates']/tbody/tr/td")))
            
            # so far css selector works but also times out
            # tag_name span also works but it pulls everything, data cleaning needed
            # class name not working
            credit_names = []
            content = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.credit-name')
            #content = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'cred-name')))
            #content = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'credit-name')
            
            for i in content:
                #print(i.text)
                credit_names.append(i.text)
            print('cred_name', credit_names)
            
            # grab data on category points
            sus_data = []
            content = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'num')

            for points in content:
                sus_data.append(points.text)
            print('sus_scores', sus_data)


            # add all these things into df
            df_scorecard = pd.DataFrame()
            
            # exit scorecard page
            driver.back()
            
            # exit building profile page
            driver.back()
            
           
        # move onto next page#############################################
    
        # Perform your desired actions on each page here
        # Add some wait here for next page load
        # Check if the next button is disabled
        next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//div[@id="result-grid"]//a[text()="Next"]')))
        if next_button.get_attribute('Disabled'):
            time.sleep(1)
            break  # Exit the loop if the next button is disabled
        
        else:
            # Click the next button to navigate to the next page
            time.sleep(1)
            next_button.click()
            
    except IndexError:
        break

# quit the chrome driver option
driver.quit()
```

Basically, when the code reaches the # grab specific credit name block and the # grab data on category points, if I use By.CSS without webdriverwait it finds most of the items, but not all of them, additionally after a certain number of buildings have been viewed it may time out. When I try to use webdriver wait it usually times out. If I use By.CLASS_NAME selenium cannot find any elements, even though the class name is correct. If I use By.tag_name it finds all of the 'span' elements on the page which is not ideal while trying to find 'credit-name' or 'num' specific elements.

Overall I need help understanding why the methods above are not working and any other suggestions anyone may have. I am decent at coding in python but am very new at selenium.

Thanks!